# 3d printing from an object created in blender

Tags: objects, faces, 3d-printing

I am trying to 3d print an object i have created using facebuilder (using this tutorial specifically: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WH7s-IPIeM).

I have successfully built the facial object in blender but my problem is that it just won't print after i've sliced it in cura, perhaps because it doesn't seem to be watertight. I have tried mesh repairs and other things in blender but nothing seems to work.

I have also tried to do repairs and make the object watertight in cura and freecad but to no avail.

If possible I can attach the file(s) I'm trying to print.

How can I make the object I've created in facebuilder 3d printable?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: thanks rick, i'll try that.

Comment: i'll have to get a .blend file if i can because that's the only file allowed